# How to stop colours recycling

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a heatmap in r using filled.contour, and I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like the one below, but the colours are recycled, maiking it pretty useless. What am I doing wrong?

```
x <- c(seq(15, 75, by = 5))
y <- rep(c(100,200,300,400,500, 600, 700, 800),each=length(x))
z <- sample(0:34, length(y), replace=TRUE)
z <- z/10000

d <- data.frame(x, y, z)


resolution <- 0.1

a <- interp(x=d$x, y=d$y, z=d$z, 
        xo=seq(min(d$x),max(d$x),by=resolution), 
        yo=seq(min(d$y),max(d$y),by=resolution),
        duplicate="mean")

MyHeatMapColours <-colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","springgreen","royalblue"))(50)

filled.contour(a, col = MyHeatMapColours, nlevels = 49)
```

Comment: `could not find function "interp"`

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess that `interp` is from package:akima. Your example is hardly minimal, since it takes an ungodly long time to run, so I cut down the resiolution with no loss of generality. I think that it is safer to use "levels" rather than "nlevels", although I cannot tell you why this is so:

```
library(akima)   # which does have an `interp`-function
x <- c(seq(15, 75, by = 5))
y <- rep(c(100,200,300,400,500, 600, 700, 800),each=length(x))
z <- sample(0:34, length(y), replace=TRUE)
z <- z/10000

d <- data.frame(x, y, z)
resolution <- 0.5

a <- interp(x=d$x, y=d$y, z=d$z, 
        xo=seq(min(d$x),max(d$x),by=resolution), 
        yo=seq(min(d$y),max(d$y),by=resolution),
        duplicate="mean")

MyHeatMapColours <-colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","springgreen","royalblue"))(49) 
#colors are supposed to be one less than length of levels.

filled.contour(a, col = MyHeatMapColours, 
               levels = seq(min(z),max(z), length=50))
```

[image]